# If X ~Poi(λ) proof that $\lambda > i$, $P(X \le i) \le \frac{(e)^{-λ} (eλ)^i}{i^i}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Please I need help showing that if X is a random variable, X ~Poi(λ) proof that $P(X \le i) \le \frac{(e)^{-λ} (eλ)^i}{i^i}$

Comment: This is the principle of the zero-context question pushed rather far...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Chernoff bound to derive this.

For $s>0$,
$P(X \leq i) = P(-sX \geq -s i) = P(e^{-sX} \geq e^{-si}) \leq \frac{E[e^{-sX}]}{e^{-si}} = e^{s i} e^{\lambda (e^{-s}-1)}$ where the Inequality is Markov's inequality.

Now, optimize this bound over $s>0$ under the assumption that $\lambda>i$.

Comment: Except that the upper bound suggested in the question is absurd, hence no, the OP cannot "use a Chernoff bound to derive this".

Comment: @Did - oops, fixed the inequality on $\lambda$. But choosing $s=\log(\lambda/i)$ does establish the desired bound.

Comment: With the restriction that $\lambda>i$, yes, the inequality holds. But not without it (fix $i=1$ and consider the limit $\lambda\to0$). The question does not mention such a restriction. In this context, your previous typo (now corrected) stating that the result was ok for $\lambda<i$, was unfortunate....

Comment: @Did - the restriction is in the question title????

Comment: Somehow I had missed it. Sorry for the noise.